# nix nixlang: undefined variable pkgs in default.nix via nix-build -A hello but works in nix repl

Tags: nix

I wrote a very simple default.nix file with which I should be able to build the gnu hello package (similiar to nix-pills).

But now i've come across an error:

> [jane@nixos:~/graphviz]$ nix-build -A hello
>
> error: undefined variable 'pkgs' at /home/jane/graphviz/default.nix:3:47

this is the source code :

```
[jane@nixos:~/graphviz]$ cat default.nix 
{
    pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {}; 
    mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix pkgs;
    hello = import ./hello.nix { inherit mkDerivation ;};
    
}
```

which makes absolutely no sense (to me) as right the line above i defined pkgs.

As i couldn't see what's wrong i opened nix repl and entered the lines.

```
nix-repl> pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {} 

nix-repl> mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix pkgs

nix-repl> hello = import ./hello.nix { inherit mkDerivation ;}  

nix-repl> hello
«derivation /nix/store/g2y6sf5q236icvv2gwyg0lnij3mkr36j-hellooo.drv»
```

And voila there it works. So i don't understand why it fails with default.nix. I could only imagine that default.nix is somewhat special but syntax wise it must be fine otherwise nix repl wouldn't work as well.

**Can anyone explain why i get this undefined variable error ?**

Edit: Just after asking the question i found one way to solve the undefined  variable error, if I put it like this:

```
let pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {}; mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix pkgs;
in
{
    hello = import ./hello.nix { inherit mkDerivation ;};
    
}
```

it works.

But my original question still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{ }` syntax only defines a value. It does not bring the attributes in it into scope. You can use the `rec { }` syntax which does do both.

```
rec {
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {}; 
  mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix pkgs;
  hello = import ./hello.nix { inherit mkDerivation ;};
}
```

What the `nix repl` does is essentially create a `let` binding every time name something. Your repl session can be thought of as this expression being built interactively:

```
let pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
in /* nixlang scope on 2nd prompt */
  let mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix pkgs
  in /* nixlang scope on 3rd prompt */
    let hello = import ./hello.nix { inherit mkDerivation ;}
      /* nixlang scope on 4th prompt */
    in hello
```

To illustrate the distinction between attribute set creation and name binding, you *could* name the attribute set and use it in its own definition

```
let
  myScope = {
    # myScope is like any other attribute set
    pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};

    # laziness permits the attributes inside to reference myScope
    mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix myScope.pkgs;
    hello = import ./hello.nix { inherit (myScope) mkDerivation ;};
  };
in
  # the value of this file is the myScope attribute set
  myScope
```

This is equivalent to the `rec` example, but brings only a single name into scope: `myScope`.

Comment: Thx for your answer , so if I understand correctly by default variables aren't brought into scope to avoid evaluating them ?  (and therefore saving computation)

Comment: It probably helps a bit. Another example of a reason is that this `{ key, value }: rec { key = key; value = value + 1; }` produces an attribute set with fields that produce infinite recursion. So if `rec` was the only behavior, you'd need to more renaming and you'd have to be careful to avoid accidental recursion.